# How to deploy EJB EAR file to JBoss 7 with JDeveloper

Tags: jboss7.x, javabeans, jdeveloper

I have a project done in JDeveloper 11g that are EJBs.  I can write these to an EAR file.  Now, how do I deploy this file to the JBoss app server?  This was previously deployed to a JBoss 6 server but ever since I upgraded to 7 and nothing works.  Will the same beans work in 7?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace or errors in the console, so that we could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an "Application Server" connection in JDeveloper to your JBoss server and then from your application menu choose deploy... to the server.
Or you can create the EAR in JDeveloper, pick it up with the JBoss admin console and deploy it.
Whether it will work depends on what is in your application.

Comment: Thanks - the JBoss server is a linux box that I do not have access to.  So it's probably not possible, right?